# NULL row disappearing on PDO only

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Looking for optimizing SQL requests to speed up a 20 seconds load page. We must reduce the number of request we have. Theses are the current requests:

```
                SELECT
                    P.[Starting Date] as current_promo
                FROM [Sales Price] P
                WHERE P.[Item No_] = :id
                  AND P.[Ending Date] >= getdate()
                  AND P.[Starting Date] <= getdate()
              ORDER BY P.[Starting Date] ASC;

                SELECT
                    P.[Starting Date] as current_promo
                FROM [Purchase Line Discount] P
                WHERE P.[Item No_] = :id
                  AND (P.[Line Discount_] > 0 OR P.[Line Discount_2] > 0)
                  AND (P.[Ending Date] >= getdate() OR P.[Ending Date] = '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')
                  AND (P.[Starting Date] <= getdate() OR P.[Starting Date] = '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')
              ORDER BY P.[Starting Date] ASC;

                SELECT
                    P.[Lot Quantity] as lot,
                    P.[Free Quantity] as free
                FROM [Purchase Price] P
                WHERE P.[Item No_] = :id
                  AND (P.[Ending Date] >= getdate() OR P.[Ending Date] = '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')
                  AND (P.[Starting Date] <= getdate() OR P.[Starting Date] = '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')
              ORDER BY P.[Ending Date] ASC;

                SELECT
                    P.[Starting Date] as next_promo
                FROM [Purchase Price] P
                WHERE P.[Item No_] = :id
                  AND P.[Minimum Quantity] = 1
                  AND P.[Ending Date] > P.[Starting Date]
                  AND P.[Starting Date] > getdate()
              ORDER BY P.[Starting Date] ASC;
```

We do need only first result of each query. Okay, I can do a `TOP 1`, no problem with that. But I still need to concatenate theses 4 requests. Here is one of my drafts :

```
SELECT
       sales_promo,
       purchase_promo,
       lot, free,
       next_promo
FROM
     (
       SELECT TOP 1 P.[Starting Date] as sales_promo
       FROM [Purchase Line Discount] P
       WHERE P.[Item No_] = :id
         AND (P.[Line Discount _] > 0 OR P.[Line Discount _ 2] > 0)
         AND (P.[Ending Date] >= getdate() OR P.[Ending Date] = '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')
         AND (P.[Starting Date] <= getdate() OR P.[Starting Date] = '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')
       ORDER BY P.[Starting Date] ASC
       ) salesPromo FULL OUTER JOIN
     (
       SELECT TOP 1 P.[Starting Date] as purchase_promo
       FROM [Purchase Line Discount] P
       WHERE P.[Item No_] = :id
         AND (P.[Line Discount _] > 0 OR P.[Line Discount _ 2] > 0)
                 AND (P.[Ending Date] >= getdate() OR P.[Ending Date] = '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')
         AND (P.[Starting Date] <= getdate() OR P.[Starting Date] = '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')
       ORDER BY P.[Starting Date] ASC
     ) purchasePromo ON 1=1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     (
       SELECT TOP 1 P.[Lot Quantity] as lot, P.[Free Quantity] as free
       FROM [Purchase Price] P
       WHERE P.[Item No_] = :id
         AND (P.[Ending Date] >= getdate() OR P.[Ending Date] = '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')
         AND (P.[Starting Date] <= getdate() OR P.[Starting Date] = '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')
       ORDER BY P.[Ending Date] ASC
     ) lotandfee ON 1=1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     (
       SELECT TOP 1 P.[Starting Date] as next_promo
       FROM [Purchase Price] P
       WHERE P.[Item No_] = :id
         AND P.[Minimum Quantity] = 1
         AND P.[Ending Date] > P.[Starting Date]
         AND P.[Starting Date] > getdate()
       ORDER BY P.[Starting Date] ASC
     ) nextPromo ON 1=1
```

Perfect, this is working !

**The issue** :

On some of subrequests, I have 0 results. When I do this request directly on database, I have no problems, `null` when I do have no result on a subrequest and a result on a second subrequest. But when I do this with PDO, whenever I have a subrequest with 0 result, I end up with the entire line disappearing !

Here is another draft, giving the same result :

```
SELECT
       sales_promo
       purchase_promo,
       lot, free,
       next_promo
FROM
     (
       SELECT q.* FROM (SELECT NULL) AS d (dummy) LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT TOP 1 P.[Starting Date] as sales_promo
         FROM [Purchase Line Discount] P
         WHERE P.[Item No_] = :id
           AND (P.[Line Discount _] > 0 OR P.[Line Discount _ 2] > 0)
           AND (P.[Ending Date] >= getdate() OR P.[Ending Date] = '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')
           AND (P.[Starting Date] <= getdate() OR P.[Starting Date] = '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')
         ORDER BY P.[Starting Date] ASC
       ) AS q ON 1=1
       ) salesPromo,
     (
       SELECT q.* FROM (SELECT NULL) AS d (dummy) LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT TOP 1 P.[Starting Date] as purchase_promo
       FROM [Purchase Line Discount] P
       WHERE P.[Item No_] = :id
         AND (P.[Line Discount _] > 0 OR P.[Line Discount _ 2] > 0)
                 AND (P.[Ending Date] >= getdate() OR P.[Ending Date] = '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')
         AND (P.[Starting Date] <= getdate() OR P.[Starting Date] = '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')
       ORDER BY P.[Starting Date] ASC
       ) AS q ON 1=1
     ) purchasePromo,
     (
       SELECT q.* FROM (SELECT NULL) AS d (dummy) LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT TOP 1 P.[Lot Quantity] as lot, P.[Free Quantity] as free
       FROM [Purchase Price] P
       WHERE P.[Item No_] = :id
         AND (P.[Ending Date] >= getdate() OR P.[Ending Date] = '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')
         AND (P.[Starting Date] <= getdate() OR P.[Starting Date] = '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')
       ORDER BY P.[Ending Date] ASC
       ) AS q ON 1=1
     ) lotandfee,
     (
       SELECT q.* FROM (SELECT NULL) AS d (dummy) LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT TOP 1 P.[Starting Date] as next_promo
       FROM [Purchase Price] P
       WHERE P.[Item No_] = :id
         AND P.[Minimum Quantity] = 1
         AND P.[Ending Date] > P.[Starting Date]
         AND P.[Starting Date] > getdate()
       ORDER BY P.[Starting Date] ASC
       ) AS q ON 1=1
     ) nextPromo
```

Comment: You can use window function and join each query on based on new column created by window function(row_number).

Comment: @Nitika I'm trying to understand how to work with window function... Can you do a full subrequest with this ?